# How can I make to absolute positioned DIVs share the width of the outer DIV?

Tags: html, css

For a weekly calendar I need to position the DIVs for the events in an outer DIV for the day.
To position these DIVs at the correct time I tried using the absolute positioning with the top value, but this leads to the DIVs being stacked on one another if I have multiple events at the same time.
I now want these DIVs to "share" the width of the outer DIV.

I already tried the flex solution but doesn't seem to work with absolute positions.
Also putting the DIVs in an additional DIV to position them is not an option.

Does anyone have an idea to a solution? Thanks!

```css
    .tagclmn {
        width: 300px;
        font: 12.0px Helvetica;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .veranstaltung {
        border-radius: 4px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
        <div class="tagclmn">
            <div class="veranstaltung" style="top: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red;">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="title">Testvorlesung</div>
                    <div class="time">10:00 - 12:00 st</div>
                    <div class="place">W.11.010</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="veranstaltung" style="top: 400px; height: 200px; background-color: green;">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="title">Testvorlesung 2</div>
                    <div class="time">12:00 - 14:00 st</div>
                    <div class="place">W.11.010</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="veranstaltung" style="top: 400px; height: 200px; background-color: blue;">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="title">Testvorlesung 3</div>
                    <div class="time">12:00 - 14:00 st</div>
                    <div class="place">W.11.003</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioned elements take up no space in their parent....and do not contribute to layout. You may need to re-think your approach.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using `position: absolute` for `veranstaltung`

Answer (score 0):

Much of this can be managed with CSS-Grid.

If we know the number of complete hours available we can use that to set a number of rows for our grid.

Say we operate a diary from 9am to 5pm, that would mean 8 rows.

Then we add classes to tell each appointment how long it lasts (span) and at which hour it starts (start).

Then:

```css
.tagclmn {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, minmax(3em, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 4px;
}

[class^="span"] {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}

.span-2 {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.span-3 {
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}

.start-2 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.start-4 {
  grid-row-start: 4;
}

.start-8 {
  grid-row-start: 8;
}
```

```html
<div class="tagclmn">
  <div class="veranstaltung span-2 start-2" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Testvorlesung</div>
      <div class="time">10:00 - 12:00 st</div>
      <div class="place">W.11.010</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="veranstaltung span-1 start-4" style="background-color: lightgreen;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Testvorlesung 2</div>
      <div class="time">12:00 - 13:00 st</div>
      <div class="place">W.11.010</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="veranstaltung span-2 start-4" style="background-color: lightblue;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Testvorlesung 3</div>
      <div class="time">12:00 - 14:00 st</div>
      <div class="place">W.11.003</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="veranstaltung span-1 start-8" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Testvorlesung</div>
      <div class="time">16:00 - 17:00 st</div>
      <div class="place">W.11.010</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="veranstaltung span-3 start-4" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Testvorlesung</div>
      <div class="time">12:00 - 15:00 st</div>
      <div class="place">W.11.010</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** the order of the `.veranstaltung` in the DOM is NOT related to their visual order which means that, provided the correct untility classes are applied, the appointments can be added non-sequentially in the HTML.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply add a width of 50% and a left of 50% to the second item, but i'm not sure if it's the answer you're looking for.

```html
<div class="tagclmn">
    <div class="veranstaltung" style="top: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: red;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">Testvorlesung</div>
            <div class="time">10:00 - 12:00 st</div>
            <div class="place">W.11.010</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="veranstaltung" style="top: 400px; height: 200px; background-color: green; width:50%;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">Testvorlesung 2</div>
            <div class="time">12:00 - 14:00 st</div>
            <div class="place">W.11.010</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="veranstaltung" style="top: 400px; height: 200px; background-color: blue;width:50%; left:50%">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">Testvorlesung 3</div>
            <div class="time">12:00 - 14:00 st</div>
            <div class="place">W.11.003</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way you can also increase the hieght of lesson 3. for example it is from 13:00 till 15:00, it still works